# Why does my jQuery .off() method not trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm using `jQuery` for the following script instead of `$` because the page i'm working on already has `$` declared for something else:

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery(document).height() - .10*jQuery(document).height()) {
        jQuery(window).off('scroll')
        console.log("At Bottom and more than 1.");
    }
})
```

The code i'm using to sub jQuery's `$` to just `jQuery` is this;

```
var jqry = document.createElement('script'); 
jqry.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqry);
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming from your condition not from the `.off()`, check if your condition is applying correctly.

here is an example code of `.off()` with scroll and it's working fine

```js
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function() {
    console.log(jQuery(window).scrollTop());
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
        jQuery(window).off('scroll')
        console.log("At Bottom and more than 50.");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: The result seems to be the same. I want to completely stop the scroll event if a user reaches the bottom of the page and trigger a new event when they do. My issue is that my console is being spammed with `console.log("At Bottom and more than 1.")`. So it means that my condition is being but the .off method is not triggering.

Comment: you need to know that the scroll will not trigger every 1+ it depends on how fast you are scrolling so it might increase 10 or 15 at a time thats why I'm using [> or =]